# Where to discuss poker hands (besides here)?

Tags: hand-history

Being a programmer I have used the mother site to Poker.StackExchange ([StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)) for years and really believe in how the voting system brings out the best answers.  However, there must be sites for discussing poker hands that currently have more traffic than this?  What other sites would you recommend for discussing hands?

I have been playing poker for a long time, but have not discussed hands online before.  When I have searched for poker discussion rooms the results seem overwhelming and it is hard to know where I would find good expert opinions and not just some random players throwing out their opinion.

Comment: I am closing this as a duplicate as its similar to that question. The answer provided on the other question contains several other sites. However, please post your hand histories on here as well as the more we get the more traffic we are likely to see.

Comment: Accepted, I did not find the question while searching for it.